# Using React, I want to save form inputs as object using state. Only one input is being recognized and the other as undefined

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, state, setstate

I cannot figure out how to get the "fName" input to update the state of the "inputObj". What am I missing, because it seems like I am pretty close? Then again, I may be way off. I am just logging it to the console for now through the `ListGamerData` component.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import AddGamerData from './AddGamerData';
import ListGamerData from './ListGamerData';

const HandleForm = () => {
const [uNameArray, setUNameArray] = useState([]);
const [profileArray, setProfileArray] = useState([]);
const [inputObj, setInputObj] = useState("");

const checkUser = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (uNameArray.includes(inputObj.uName) !== true) {
        setUNameArray([...uNameArray, inputObj.uName]);
        setProfileArray([...profileArray, inputObj]);
        setInputObj({fName: "", uName: ""});
    } else {
        alert("Gamer Tag already exists. Please try again.");
    }
}

const addUser = (event) => {
    checkUser(event);
};

return (
    <div className="handle-form-component">
        <h1>Gamer Data</h1>
        <p><strong>Enter gamer data below:</strong></p>
        <form onSubmit={addUser}>
            <AddGamerData inputObj={inputObj} setInputObj={setInputObj} />
        </form>
    <ListGamerData uNameArray={uNameArray} profileArray={profileArray} />
    </div>   
)}
export default HandleForm;
```

And here's the `AddGamer` component.

```
const AddGamerData = ({inputObj, setInputObj}) => {
const inputIsEmpty = () => inputObj.uName === "";

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputObj({[event.target.name] : event.target.value})
}

return (
    <div className="add-gamer-data-component">
        <input
            type="text"
            name="fName"
            placeholder="Enter First Name"
            value={inputObj.fName}
            onChange={handleChange}
        /><br></br>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="uName"
            placeholder="Enter Gamer Tag"
            value={inputObj.uName}
            onChange={handleChange}
        /><br></br>
        <button disabled={inputIsEmpty()} >Add Gamer</button>
    </div>
)}
export default AddGamerData;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the `handleChange` function which overrides your object on every input change.

This change ensures that the old values of the state object are being carried over to the new state:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputObj((curr) => ({
      ...curr,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };
```